# $('#id').focus() not working focusing on an input field inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a div defines as

```
<div ng-repeat="mine in me2">
  <div ng-show="dataon">

    <autocomplete attr-input-id="myid" attr-placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="dataloc"
     data="data" on-type="getLocations" click-activation="true" ng-click=getLocations() 
     on-select="selectedLocationSpecials"></autocomplete>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$('#myid')` not working when i call it inside a function.

Comment: Show that function also

Comment: what error are you getting? how does the real html look like, is the same id used twice?

Comment: i am calling $('#myid').focus()  it is not getting focused on that input feild

Comment: @RajDubey Where and how do you call $('#myid').focus() ? And where is the element with ID myid?

Comment: @OscarSiauw  <autocomplete attr-input-id=**"myid"**

Comment: That means you have multiple elements with ID myid if you put that in your ng-repeat

Comment: no its  the only div with this id, as there is an ng-show condition over there.

Comment: so where is the code where you call $('#myid').focus() ? And what is your output HTML looks like?

Comment: Its an normal input autocomplete is an directive  and i have called .focus inside my controller

Comment: where is the code in your question?

Comment: @RajDubey Any reason why you don't want to use `ngFocus` direction from Angular? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus